# named arrays as dataframe ->col.names(df) = names(array)

Tags: r

I have a named array called namearray as

```
> namearray
evntidABCD evntidWXYZ     
         1          2 
> names(namearray)
[1] "evntidABCD" "evntidWXYZ"

> nrow(namearray)
[1] 2
```

From this namearray, I would like to construct a dataframe namedf such that the col.names of namedf should be exactly as the namearray. And the number of rows of namedf should be 1 less than the namearray, as the first row in the namearray is the column names.

I tried the following code and it gives me the following error.

```
>namedf<-data.frame()
>col.names(namedf)<-names(namearray)

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("evntidABCD", "evntidWXYZ")) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> namearray
evntidABCD evntidWXYZ     
         1          2
```

That is surely not looking like an 'array'. Named 'vector' perhaps.

If you create a dataframe with no columns then there is nothing to to name. This will extend a "null dataframe"

```
namevec <- c(evntidABCD=1, evntidWXYZ =2)  
namedf<-data.frame()
namedf <- setNames( rbind(namedf,namevec), names(namevec) )
```

(Justin's suggestion is better.)

Comment: Converting it to a `list` and using that will work!  `data.frame(as.list(namearray))`